# Why do some good reputable sites like Stack Overflow still use Table tags?

Tags: html, standards

It's odd but true, I've seen it in a lot of places, and I'm 100% sure its not hard at all to lose the table tags, but also, it's much more scalable not to use tables.

Why then, do some good websites insist on using tables?

EDIT: the table tags used here are for pure layout (check the "asked, viewed, active" label on the right panel), or check the tags page, maybe it is tabulated data but they're using the table to layout, knowing that using divs is much neater and more scalable and maintainable... I just wonder why.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that there is nothing wrong with using tables to represent tabular data (although many of the tables on SO do not fall under that heading)

Comment: Does it really matter to write `<div style="display:table;">` instead of `<table>`?

Comment: @ceving Well it's a different semantic: `<table>` says that there is tabular data in it. `<div>` is some generic tag that pretty much says nothing ^^

Comment: @ceving yes it does matter... for a robot (Google) a ´<table>´ has a meaning (tabular data), while ´<div style="display:table;">´ is just a division with a certain style. That's why in html we have new tags like ´<menu>´ and ´<header>´ :)

Comment: @Ayyash: If you want to aim a question like this at the SO devs, try asking on meta.stackoverflow.com. That's a more appropriate place to ask. But you'd need to word your question much less subjectively, otherwise it'd just get closed there too.

Comment: this question is NOT argumentative! i seriously want to know the technical reasons that push a good website backwards like that, in order to present an argument to my customers! why has my question been closed?!!

Comment: @spudley, yeah i see ur point, probably wording :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not always easy. If you want to support older browsers you can easily get into trouble. For example: try to align something centered and in the middle of a bigger box.

Also if you have an older page you need to see that it costs time/money to change the code. And as long as it's working properly there is often something more important to use your resources on.